# Oracle date format:varchar to date then char and then date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a varchar value `'20-OCT-2019'` I want to load the same in date column with the format `'10/20/2019'`.

I have tried below but it is not giving expected output.

```
select to_date(to_char(to_date('20-OCT-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') 
  from dual
```

Comment: date datatype is not stored in any particular format. You may simply   use the inner most `to_date` to convert your string to date and load into date column. While displaying, use `to_char` with the desired format

Comment: Don't store your dates as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle, DATE values do not have a particular format such as `DD-MON-YYYY` OR `DD/MM/RR` or etc. All DATE fields contain sub-fields for the century, year, month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds, meaning that all DATE fields in Oracle are really timestamp values with a precision of one second. [Oracle will by default convert a DATE to a character string using the `DD-MON-YY` format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413), but this is just default format - it does not mean that the date is stored in `DD-MON-RR` format.

Comment: Does it mean we need to take care of format while displaying the data and not while inserting the date in table?

Comment: So basically(for all other readers), I just need a single to_date function to load values in date column  and I should to_char to display the output in specific date format.

Comment: @Shubhangi yes, exactly. Internally, an Oracle stored `DATE` is 7 bytes of binary that is not human-readable. The default display format will depend on the client and your [settings for territory, language etc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html).

Comment: @Shubhangi: in response to your first comment, you need to use a format in your call to TO_DATE() when inserting a date value into the database, and you need to use a format with TO_CHAR() when extracting a date from the database. In response to your second comment, that's correct.

Comment: @Shubhangi Just an additional comment to what Bob and William have already said: you only need to use `to_date()` to convert a string into DATE datatype. If the date you are inserting is already in DATE datatype, then you don't need to convert it before inserting, e.g. `insert into t1 (date_col) values (sysdate);`. Don't ever use `to_date()` on something that is already of DATE datatype, because you cause Oracle to have to implicitly convert the date into a string and back into a date. It's unnecessary and could cause errors if the format mask you use isn't the same as NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load your string data in a string column. So the outermost `to_date` conversion has no sense, but if you want to display in the desired format you need such a conversion below :

```
select  to_char(
                to_date('20-OCT-2019','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
                   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')
    as "Appearance in New Format"                   
  from dual;

    Appearance in New Format
            10/20/2019
```

without forgetting to use `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` option against your different local language settings being other than English(In this case `OCT: October is an abbreviation in English Language`)

*P.S. actually you don't save a date column in a certain format as @Bob Jarvis pointed out but they're shown as depending on your `nls_date_format` settings such as setting with this sample :*

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`

Comment: I have string value. I want to save in date column with a specific format. Inner to date function used to change the string to date. to_char used to change the date format.and again to date used to change string to date.

Comment: @Shubhangi actually you don't save a date column in a certain format as Bob pointed out but they're shown as depending on your `nls_date_format` settings such as setting with this sample : `alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';`